# Exposing private function without refs in React / otherwise digging height info for react-infinite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite

NOTE: **we need getStyle().height before the component is rendered**

I have my own react-infinite parameter which essentially just goes through its children and passes the heights to Infinite. This works fine when the components have height specified in props. Eg. these work just fine:

```
<InfAdapter><div style={{height:420}}/></InfAdapter>
```

and

```
<InfAdapter><Foo height={420}/></InfAdapter>
```

Where Foo.render():

```
return <div style={{height:this.props.height}}/>
```

Because reasons, I would much rather pass style for Foo's child like this:

```
return <div style={this.getStyle()}/>
```

The problem is that if I use the getStyle approach, I can't figure out a way to pass the height to InfAdapter.

So far I've tried the following:

1. adding {getStyle:this.getStyle} to getDefaultProps. Fails probably because getDefaultProps does not have context.
2. doing setProps(...) in componentDidMount, complains that the component already has parent
3. doing setProps(...) in componentWillMount, complains that the component has not been rendered yet

Fwiw InfAdapter gets the heights like this:

```
this.props.children.map(this.getHeight);

getHeight(c){
    return c.props.height||c.props.style.height
}
```

Passing this.style instead of this.getStyle() would also be fine, yet less ideal. As would be digging props.style.height from the child div, but I doubt this is possible since we need height for InfAdapter before we render Foo.

Comment: Can't you change getHeight(c) to call `c.getStyle().height`?

Comment: Can't call c.getStyle()... If I could it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by a really stupid hack.

While JSX is transformed to JS, I check if the classes have a style field, and if they have, create a getDefaultProps() method that returns {style:whateverWasSpecifiedInThisStyle}.

Extremely ugly, but it get's the job done.